# Apple iAd is not letting me run ads in my free kids' app! How to get around this?

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, iad

I just spend oodles of time getting iAd to work in my AIR app for kids and now Apple tells me that it no longer supports iAd for kids apps! Any advice? The app sometimes has tens of thousands of downloads in a day. Do I take the loss and move on or is there any way to re-release this app as not "kids only"? Has anyone done this before? Thanks!

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Apple policies.

Comment: Great question for anyone who has tried to make a quality kid's app!

Answer (score 2):

> Note: Apps designed for children are not allowed to run rich media ads
>   I think that there is no solution about it.

The thing that is not clear to me is if this rule is valid only for `Made for Kid` category, you select that category in ITC when you set the parental rating. I guess that is the only way that they can recognize that. Try to see if creating a new upgrade you can remove the "Made for kids" flag.

Comment: Thank you, Andrea! The app is not specially "made for kids", but it is rated 4+. Do you know whether if I add "infrequent fantasy violence" (which it definitely doesn't have!) to make it 9+, is that the cut-off age to allow advertising? Does anyone know what the cut-off age is?

Comment: Yes 9+ seems to be the limit (is hard to say if it will solve), but I'm not getting the issue. Did Apple rejected you application for that?

Comment: Having the app rated at 4+ should not be an issue. If you've checked the "Made For Kids" box below the rating system in iTunes Connect you need to undo this. I believe it is editable while your app status is "Waiting for Upload", so issuing an update may be necessary. I have multiple apps with a 4+ rating that receive iAd impressions with no issues.I have also recently submitted and been approved for another so a change in Apple's policies is unlikely.

Answer (score 1):

If I'm not wrong, you cant air ads on kids apps. Maybe contact apple developer support and get the age bracket of your app changed? Thats the only thing I can think of..

Comment: Hi Raghav - thanks for your answer! Will ads run off an app which is 9+, do you know? I can't find the information anywhere online.

Comment: Im not sure either, but what I would do is that I would contact developer support,(Google it, they have contact numbers for centers all over the world) and while asking them for help with changing the age bracket, I would enquire about the 9+ thing as well. And I think you should avoid adding Infrequent Fantasy Violence to it(Your other comment on Andrea's post) as well, it might get you in trouble with the Apple App Review Team!

Answer (score 1):

You can release an update to the app and change the setting in iTunes Connect so that you app is not "Made for kids".
However, ads in general are frowned upon in kids apps. Although they're not specifically illegal, according to COPPA.
Also, if an Apple app reviewer decides that your app is targeted at kids anyway, they might reject it based on their policy of no iADs for kids apps.

Regarding COPPA's rules on ads for kids:  http://www.ftc.gov/tips-advice/business-center/guidance/complying-coppa-frequently-asked-questions

*"I want to run ads on my child-directed websites and apps.  What do I need to know to make sure that I am complying with COPPA?
There are a number of questions you must find answers to before you enter into an arrangement with any entity to serve advertising to run on your child-directed sites and services.  These include: 
Is there a way to control the type of advertising that appears on the sites and services?  (e.g., can you stipulate and contract only for contextual advertising, and can you prohibit behavioral advertising or retargeting?)
 What categories of information will be collected from users on the sites and services in connection with the ads they are served?  Will persistent identifiers be collected for purposes other than support for internal operations?  Will geolocation information be collected in connection with the ads served?

You should make informed decisions before you permit advertising to run on your sites and services.  Depending on what advertising choices you make, you may be required to notify parents in your online privacy policies and in a direct notice, and obtain verifiable parental consent, before you permit advertising to occur.  Remember that the amended Rule holds you liable for the collection of information that occurs on or through your sites and services, even if you yourself do not engage in such collection."*

Comment: Unfortunately, it won't help you but I can try to explain what is going on here.  COPPA makes it illegal to collect any Personally Identifiable Information about a child under 13, and by positioning your app as targeting kids under 13 Apple doesn't want to get in trouble because it collects a unique identifier in iAds (any unique identifier is now considered to be Personally Identifiable in the new version of COPPA).

Answer (score 0):

If you want to monetise your app with advertising, you have little choice but to use an ad-network that can specifically provide ads for your target age group, and that is COPPA-compliant.  Apple's ad network is neither as far as I know.  Try Superawesome.tv or Ads4Kids - they may have an SDK you can add to your app for delivering ad campaigns appropriate for children.